# Magento: send a custom ordermail with a xml attachment

Tags: php, xml, email, magento, attachment

I have to make a Magento plugin that sends a copy of a successful order to a business partner.

This email should have an XML-attachment with all orderdata + customerdata.

I can create a simple send function like http://www.atwix.com/magento/email-sending-feature/.

But where should I call this function when a order is finished? And how can I create an XML-file with all data?

Thanks!

Comment: I would observe orders and react on that. Probably this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434256/magento-observer-event-on-order-place-not-firing

Comment: @philipp is right. Create the observer class and a method using that response and after that Magento has functions to get the current order and all the products inside the order. Google them like that and you will find the answers. When you have all the data, create a file using basic PHP, add the corresponding headers to make it XML, add the content as strings encapsulated in tags and you're done. Don't ask somebody else to do your job. ;)